# Python dictionary, basic key value question

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I can't work this bit out...
Could someone explain to me how the value of the key gets assigned to variable 'language'?

I understand the if statement checks favourite_languages for a matching name, but how does the value associated with key [name] get slotted in?

```
favourite_languages = {
  'jen': 'python',
  'sarah': 'c',
  'edward': 'ruby',
  'phil': 'python'
}

friends = ['phil', 'sarah']
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
  print(f"Hi {name.title()}.")

  if name in friends:
    language = favourite_languages[name].title()
    print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")
```

Output...

```
Hi Jen.
Hi Sarah.

Sarah, I see you love C!
Hi Edward.
Hi Phil.
Phil, I see you love Python!
```

Comment: What do you mean? There's obviously the assignment statement there, right?

Comment: So you didn't write this code? If not, that's okay, to understand it, one thing you can easily do is at `print` statements at each step you are confused about and see the values of variables and how they change. Then, it'll start to make sense. Also, consider `print(type(variable_name))` to understand the type of the variable(s) in case that is also confusing you.

Comment: Use a debugger.  There are numerous ones available for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code, it looks like you are iterating over each of the keys of the items in your `favourite_languages` dictionary on this line: `for name in favourite_languages.keys():`, which should be `'jen', 'sarah', 'edward', 'phil'`.

Then, there is a check to see if the current name you are looking at is in the smaller list `friends` on this line: `if name in friends:`.

If the current name is in the `friends` list, the same name you've been looking at during the first iteration loop is then used as a lookup key in your original `favourite_languages` dictionary. For example, one found name should be `'sarah'`. Here, `'sarah'` is a key, and when you check this key on the `favourite_languages` dictionary, you should get the related value: `'c'` (though this will be titlecased later).

The language that belongs with the current name is found with this line: `favourite_languages[name].title()` (and that `.title()` part [makes the result titlecased](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=title#str.title)). See, in this line of code `favourite_languages[name].title()`, `name` is the key in the `favourite_languages` dictionary, and it should give you the value related to the key you provide.

Finally, the language is printed out on the following `print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")` line. Both the `name` variable from the current name and the `language` variable that was set on this previous line `language = favourite_languages[name].title()` can then be used in the `print()` line near the end of the code.

Does that make it more clear about how the value related to the `key[name]` is accessed/used?

Comment: Thank you summea, that does make better sense, the snippet of code is pulled from the book "Python Crash Course". The line I was having trouble understanding was in fact `language = favourite_languages[name].title()` I was sort of expecting the line to call the value associated with the key explicitly. Which it sorta does in the way you've explained it.